# Send custom event from one module to another module (Parsley)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, parsley

I have created a modular application. I have two modules, for example `Module1` and `Module2`.
I have loaded these modules in my application. I am using Parsley in my application. I have loaded separate different context builder in both modules.

But when I am dispatching event from `Module1`, I am able to listen that event in that `Module1` but I am trying to listen that event in another `Module2`. I am not able to listen that event in that `Module2` through Parsley. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's hard to know how to help w/out seeing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done it by settings same application domain of all the modules...

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with you loading 2 different contexts for each module. Art gave out a really good tutorial on the matter: [Art's Flex Notes - Nested Contexts](http://artinflex.blogspot.com/2010/09/quick-dive-into-parsley-nested-contexts.html).